# AutoHotkey Code for Randomly generating number not working anymore

Tags: random, autohotkey

The following code presses the cursor every few seconds.
When I first made it, it just pressed the cursor every 5 seconds, but the game realised what I was doing.
So I changed the code, with the help of ChatGPT and made the following.
The code has been working for about 6 months, but no longer works.
Chat says the code is fine, and we went through it all, doing various tests.
But I still can't find out why the 'Random' procedure won't work.

Does anyone have any ideas.

I use it to press the curser on an silly online game when I'm out.

```
SetBatchLines -1  ; Improve script performance

Loop
{
    Random, ClickInterval, 400000, 1000000  ; Generate a random number between 400000 and 1000000 milliseconds (4.0 to 10.0 seconds)
    Click           ; Click at the current cursor position
    Sleep, ClickInterval
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there's a misunderstanding about the time duration in milliseconds.

400000 milliseconds is equal to 400 seconds, not 4 seconds.

If you intended to generate a random time between 4 and 10 seconds in milliseconds, you should use a range of 4000 to 10000 milliseconds (4 seconds to 10 seconds).

Here's the corrected code snippet:

```
SetBatchLines -1  ; Improve script performance

Loop
{
    Random, ClickInterval, 4000, 10000  ; Generate a random number between 4000 and 10000 milliseconds (4 to 10 seconds)
    Click           ; Click at the current cursor position
    Sleep, ClickInterval
}
```

Just to you understand what is happening in your code, try this:

```
SetBatchLines -1  ; Improve script performance

Loop
{
    Random, ClickInterval, 400000, 1000000
    Click
    ToolTip, % "Waiting " Round( ClickInterval/1000 ) " seconds to click again."
    count(ClickInterval)

}

count(interval) {

    Loop,% Round( interval/1000 )   {
        Sleep, 1000
        ToolTip, % "Waiting " round( interval/1000 ) - A_Index " seconds to click again."
    }
    return
}
```

Comment: ok, I changed it(just the numbers) and it works as it previously did.
This is really strange, I can't figure out how or why I changed it to the larger numbers.
Oh well.

BUT

Wow, is you answer/code awesome or what!!!???
That is really really good to know.
Perfect for checking where things are going wrong.
What can I say?
You are better than ChatGPT!

Thanks Dieisson

Comment: I'm really glad to hear that it made a difference for you